# Iterate over a dataframe with mutable state

Tags: r, iterator, closures, iteration, mutable

I want to simulate a business rule engine that features user defined variables that can be updated for every business event that passes through.

Take a data frame of historical business events ordered by date.

```
trxs <- "
id date amt
1  1    10
2  1    20
3  2    40
4  2    20
5  3    10
" %>% textConnection() %>% read.table(header = TRUE)
```

Is it possible to apply a function over each row in sequence that updates two variables `date_last_reset` and `amt_acc_since_last_reset` and adds them to the row being processed in a way that resembles the pseudo-code below?

```
if (date - date_last_reset < 2 ) {
   amt_acc_since_last_reset <- amt_acc_since_last_reset + amt
} else {
   date_last_reset <- date
   amt_acc_since_last_reset <- amt
}
add variables to row and process next
```

Which would result in

```
rtrxs <- "
id date amt date_last_reset amt_acc_since_last_reset
1  1    10   1              10
2  1    20   1              30
3  2    40   1              70 
4  2    20   1              90
5  3    10   3              10
" %>% textConnection() %>% read.table(header = TRUE)
```

Comment: You forgot to add the "resets" indicator. We can assume the first date `1` for this small example, but would need more to create a real solution outside of this example.

Comment: The most direct translation will be through a for-loop over the rows. Would that be acceptable?

Comment: You need to enhance your pseudo-code to make your intentions clearer. For example, for `i` denoting the row index, do you want to check `date[i]-date_last_reset[i-1]<2` and if so set `amt_acc_since_last_reset[i]<-amt_acc_since_last_reset[i-1]+amt[i]` with `data_last_reset` and `amt_acc_since_last_reset` initialized to `0` before entering an iteration over rows (for use with the first row)? If so, we can surely provide a solution via "apply a function".